# Error when trying to get Purchases from Android Publisher Service in a .Net Web API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-play

I have a web Api, which needs to validate purchases from Play Store. According to what I read in the google api documentation, I need to have a service account, and use its credentials to be authenticated, to be able to do what i want.
I have the following code:

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "MYSERVICEACCOUNTEMAIL@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
     new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher" }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new AndroidPublisherService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });
var data = service.Purchases.Get("MYPACKAGE", "MYPRODUCT",
            "MYTOKEN")
            .Execute();
```

It throws the following exception

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid Value [400]
Errors [
Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]
```

I have NO IDEA of what can be causing it. I searched a lot, but I didn't find something really helpful. Any kind help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem with test purchases. Url looks like this: https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/com.example.app/inapp/exampleSku/purchases/rojeslcdyyiapnqcynkjyyjh?access_token=[your_access_token_here]. Have no idea what is wrong but test purchase.

Comment: same here, stuck in the same problem other error though

Comment: If your error is forbidden, the solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471433/service-account-403-forbidden-google-play-in-app-billing-purchase-status-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question is "a little" old, but I still want to try to answer for clarification.

```
var data = service.Purchases.Get("MYPACKAGE", "MYPRODUCT",
            "MYTOKEN")
            .Execute();
```

My guess would be that this part is not entirely right. The Purchases class does not have a Get method. Before that you have to specify either (in your case):
   `service.Purchases.Products.Get(...)` -> for consumable products

`service.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get(...)` -> for subscriptions

This answer assumes you are using V2. Hope it helps anyone who is stuck.