# service account (403) Forbidden Google Play In-app Billing Purchase Status API

Tags: google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

```
<?php
include_once('./src/Google_Client.php');
include_once('./src/contrib/Google_AndroidpublisherService.php');

//user token, in json format
$ANDROIDUsertoken = '{"orderId":"12999763169054705758.1323390433376399","packageName":"org.luan.hellocpp","productId":"1","purchaseTime":1394183520430,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"rurmodmieoumgowoquecqhnv.AO-J1Ow43-aM8CXNWlUcUYmA06bIaYzZPcCJCua0lLxnihOULX27Jg6NvqNUlWMpoENxtdHCIVSm6AM2mVkiC0ABSch2JEKmu1zqsVM46L762H5ppF4AIcE"}';
$user_token= json_decode($ANDROIDUsertoken,true);

// https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts
const CLIENT_ID = '1048550291137-rfqol5nm4k9tqr0a5bupedoakhd184k4.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '1048550291137-rfqol5nm4k9tqr0a5bupedoakhd184k4@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
const KEY_FILE = './key.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($user_token['packageName']);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

$auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'),
    $key);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);

//$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
//$accessToken=$client->getAccessToken();
//$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$AndroidPublisherService = new Google_AndroidPublisherService($client);
$res = $AndroidPublisherService->inapppurchases->get($user_token['packageName'], $user_token['productId'], $user_token['purchaseToken']);

var_dump($res);
?>
```

error back :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/org.luan.hellocpp/inapp/1/purchases/rurmodmieoumgowoquecqhnv.AO-J1Ow43-aM8CXNWlUcUYmA06bIaYzZPcCJCua0lLxnihOULX27Jg6NvqNUlWMpoENxtdHCIVSm6AM2mVkiC0ABSch2JEKmu1zqsVM46L762H5ppF4AIcE: (403) Forbidden' in /var/www/debug/google/src/io/Google_REST.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/debug/google/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 /var/www/debug/google/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#2 /var/www/debug/google/src/contrib/Google_AndroidpublisherService.php(39): Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
#3 /var/www/debug/google/purchase.php(32): Google_InapppurchasesServiceResource->get('org.luan.helloc...', '1', 'rurmodmieoumgow...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/debug/google/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66
```

I got Forbidden error 403 when i use service account to query purchase status api. 
The status of Google Play Android Developer API in Google Developers Console has been setted on.
who can help me. thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just solved this problem.

You must add the service account email ("1048550291137-rfqol5nm4k9tqr0a5bupedoakhd184k4@developer.gserviceaccount.com") in your google play publish page(https://play.google.com/apps/publish/, not the google developer console).

at "Settings"-"User account & rights", "Invite new user", submit with service account email, check the "View financial reports" right, then everythings works ok~

Comment: I'm trying to verify purchases, but after the developer proyect is linked with the app, the user was invited, verified admin permissions (all checked, including financial reports), authenticate, getting the token and performing the request, it keeps responding "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.".  Any ideas?? I've got no clue whatshowever in the subject.