# Verify Google Play Receipt with Purchase Status API but always get 403 forbidden

Tags: android, api, in-app-purchase, google-play

I follow this:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

and I got my Refresh_Token and Access_Token,and then I use:

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/[packageName]/inapp/[productId]/purchases/[purchase_token]?access_token=[access_token]

and

[service account (403) Forbidden Google Play In-app Billing Purchase Status API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471433/service-account-403-forbidden-google-play-in-app-billing-purchase-status-api)

Invite my account email to be a user in google play publish page

but I still get the response an error 403 forbidden!

could someone help me?

I spent many days on this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem,

my problem point is using another Google Account to generate web application Client ID,

but that have to be generated by the product owner,or will always response 403 forbidden error!

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? I'm having the same problem, but I'm using the same account that created my app to authorize the API. Many thanks in advance...

Comment: there are too many details,so I think I can't 100% match your problem,but before I solved this problem, I went to this URL and step by step:https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ but I think maybe you didn't give your ClientID enough permition from [here](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)